# UserRole based application tab Directive Issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have created a directive to show or hide the tabs in my app depending on the user role. After logging out, the directive does not update the view and the tab does not disappear.

There is my `has-role.directive.ts` file:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/auth.service';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appHasRole]'
})
export class HasRoleDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() appHasRole: Array<string>;
    isVisible = false;

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private storage: Storage
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN').then(token => {
            if (token) {
                this.authService.getUserRoles().subscribe((data: any) => {
                    if (!data.roles) {
                        this.viewContainer.clear();
                    }
                    if (data.roles.some(r => this.appHasRole.includes(r))) {
                        if (!this.isVisible) {
                            this.isVisible = true;
                            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
                        } else {
                            this.isVisible = false;
                            this.viewContainer.clear();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the tabs are defined like this:

```
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="home">
      <ion-icon name="paper"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>{{'TABS.tab_1' | translate}}</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="dictionary" (click)="goToDictionary()">
      <ion-icon name="book"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>{{'TABS.tab_2' | translate}}</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="profile" (click)="goToProfile()">
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>{{'TABS.tab_3' | translate}}</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button *appHasRole="['moderator']" tab="admin" (click)="goToAdmin()">
      <ion-icon name="construct"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Moderator</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

The same bug also has the FAB button, but I will be able to fix it once I get a solution to the current problem of the directive.

[image]

Here is my `AuthService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { API_ENDPOINTS } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    public authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private storage: Storage,
        private platform: Platform
    ) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.checkAuthToken();
        });
    }

    private checkAuthToken() {
        this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN').then(res => {
            if (res) {
                this.authenticationState.next(true);
            } else {
                this.storage.remove('ACCESS_TOKEN');
            }
        });
    }

    login(user): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient
            .post(`${API_ENDPOINTS.API_V1}auth/token/login/`, user)
            .pipe(
                tap(async res => {
                    if (res.auth_token) {
                        await this.storage.set('ACCESS_TOKEN', res.auth_token);
                        this.authenticationState.next(true);
                    }
                })
            );
    }

    getUserRoles() {
        return this.httpClient.get(`${API_ENDPOINTS.API_V1}get-user-roles/`);
    }

    getAuthorizationToken() {
        return this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN');
    }

    logout() {
        this.storage.remove('ACCESS_TOKEN');
        this.authenticationState.next(false);
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
        return this.authenticationState.value;
    }
}
```

There is Profile Page Popover Component. The Logout Button inside Popover is defined there:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
    template: `
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item button href="https://m.chechen-dictionary.com/" target="_blank">
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="globe"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>Chechen Dictionary</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item button (click)="openTutorial()">
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="help-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>{{ 'PROFILE.tutorial' | translate }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item button (click)="logout()">
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-out"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>{{ 'PROFILE.logout' | translate }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    `
})
export class ProfileSettingsPage {
    constructor(
        public popoverCtrl: PopoverController,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router,
        private storage: Storage
    ) {}

    logout() {
        this.authService.logout();
        this.popoverCtrl.dismiss();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/home');
    }
}
```

Comment: @khashasin, can you please attach logout function?

Answer (score 0):

Logout should also redirect you to another view and destroy everything about the session.
For redirect you could import router in your constructor and call it:

```
constructor(private router: Router){}


logout() {
    this.storage.remove('ACCESS_TOKEN');
    this.authenticationState.next(false);
    this.router.navigate(["some-page"]);
}
```

Comment: This behavior is done inside Profile Page.  Click on the `logout` button does redirect you to home page. See gif image.